# Make/unmake a variable globally buffer-local depending on another variable

Tags: variables, buffer-local

I have a package with the variable `my-package--my-var` that needs to be buffer-local when `my-package-buffer-only` is `t` but global if `my-package-buffer-only` is `nil`. This is what I have so far:

```el
(defcustom my-package-buffer-only nil
  :type 'boolean
  :set (lambda (sym val)
         (when val
           (make-variable-buffer-local 'my-package--my-var))
         (set-default sym val)))

(defvar my-package--my-var nil)
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to make the variable global again if `my-package-buffer-only` is set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer from Tobias I realized that I can do what I want by using a function instead of a variable. `my-package--my-var` returns/sets the local value if `my-package-buffer-only` is set and the global value otherwise.

```el
(defcustom my-package-buffer-only nil
  :type 'boolean)

(defvar-local my-package--my-var-v nil)

(defun my-package--my-var (&optional val)
  "Return `my-package--my-var-v' or set it if VAL is non-nil.
Use the local value if `my-package-buffer-only' is set and the global value
otherwise."
  (if val
      (if my-package-buffer-only
          (setq my-package--my-var-v val)
        (setq-default my-package--my-var-v val))
    (if my-package-buffer-only
        my-package--my-var-v
      (default-value 'my-package--my-var-v))))
```

Comment: Please, do not forget to mark your answer as [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark left-hand of your answer if it solves your question. That removes this question from the list of open questions.

Comment: @Tobias I have to wait 48 hours to mark my own answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I have a strange feeling about your wish making a local variable `var` global:

1. You can always access the global value of `var` with `(default-value 'var)`.
2. You can set the global value of a local variable with `(setq-default var val)`.
3. Maybe, you should have a global version `var` **and** a local version `var-local` of your variable. AFAIK that is how most modes deal with variables that can have a global (default) value and a local value.

Nevertheless, the following lisp snippet defines two functions related to your wish.
The predicate `lispTZA-variable-made-buffer-local-p` tells you whether `make-variable-buffer-local` was applied to a variable and `lispTZA-make-variable-global` gives a symbol a fresh start as global variable.

```el
(defun lispTZA-variable-made-buffer-local-p (var)
  "Return t if VAR is local_if_set.
This is the case if `make-variable-buffer-local' was applied to VAR."
  (with-temp-buffer
        (local-variable-if-set-p var)))

(defun lispTZA-make-variable-global (var)
  "Give VAR a fresh start forgetting about localness."
  (let ((name (symbol-name var))
    (val (default-value var))
    (plist (symbol-plist var))
    (fun (symbol-function var))
    (special (special-variable-p var))) ;; Hm, should always be t. Maybe worth an assert?
    (unintern name obarray)
    (setq var (intern name)) ;; Here we have a fresh start.
    (when special
      (eval `(defvar ,var)))
    (set var val)
    (setf (symbol-plist var) plist)
    (fset var fun)))
```